# Spectral lines on a detector

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, double-slit-experiment

How can it be possible for a single electron to go through 2 slits at the same time and create 2 spectral lines on a detector. What is wrong with that theory, but at the same time produce results as if it is true?

Comment: Hmm.. Let me guess the theory is correct, as far as the current experimental evidence is concerned. What is flawed is the thought that an electron is a ball, which somehow split and goes through the two holes and somehow stick together and observed as a whole particle. An electron is a quantum object, which is *nothing* like the objects you see everyday.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This problem is an example of the wave-particle duality (which is a simplistic model of a complex quantum interaction).  Everything can be considered as a wave or a particle, although the higher the energy (that is the larger the particle's mass) the smaller the wave length.  So, a low energy photon (like a radio photon) has a very long wave length, while an electron (which has relatively larger energy) has a very short wavelength.  Still, you can consider an electron as both a wave and a particle.

When you design an experiment to test one of the aspects of an electron, than the electron will respond with that aspect.  So, in your question, you aim a very low-particle rate electron stream (or light stream for that matter) at a two-slit plate.  Since your experiment is looking for the wave aspect of the electron, that is what it will see.  Therefore, the two-slit experiment will show that an electron behaves just like a wave.

You can change the experiment a bit.  Instead of two slits, aim that electron flow at a piece of metal and you will see the electron pop off other electrons (or better, use high-energy photon - X-Rays for example - and you see the light pops electrons off of the metal).  Since you are testing the particle property of electrons or light, that is what you will see.

Basically, your experiment interacts with what you are observing in a way that modifies the results of what you see.  This is an example of the observer affects the observed.  I must also point out that very small wavelength items (such as electrons) are easier to see the particle aspects of the object instead of its wave characteristic.  On the other hand, long wavelength objects, such as radio-frequency photons are much easier to see as waves than as particles.  Still, it is possible to see radio waves as particles and electrons (or even protons) as waves.

Comment: Wave particle duality is an 80 year old hat that has been thoroughly abandoned by physics. Please don't make the OP believe in a fairytale that does nothing to help her understand quantum mechanics.

Comment: A little harsh, but I'd agree that wave particle duality is an artifice that is  not that helpful in light of quantum electrodynamics.

Comment: @CuriousOne At a BSC level, it's still being taught. This isn't absolutely wrong, and it helps understanding phenomena, before we have QED.

Comment: @Omry: Just like epicycles or the Bohr model it is absolutely wrong on all levels and we shouldn't be teaching such outdated nonsense any longer. It's not even like either the Bohr model or wave particle duality had a particularly long or successful run - they didn't have either. If you want to teach a class dedicated to the science history of physics, that's where these things belong. There is nothing wrong with telling students and laymen that the universe is filled with quantum fields (or one field) and that "particles" are simply states of those fields.

Comment: Oh you're so right.  I mean, the two-slit experiment doesn't show the wave nature of photons and electrons, and the photoelectric effect doesn't show the particle nature of photons.  Oh wait, they do show those effects.  And, until very recently, it was not possible to run an experiment that showed the wave and particle nature at the same time. So, yes the wave-particle duality comment is a very simple model of something that is very complex and may cause some problems once you get into some serious quantum mechanics. But simple helps the imagination visualize the unseeable never a bad thing.

Comment: @CuriousOne, while your answer may be sort of technically correct, you cut off so much quantum mechanics that and make certain assumptions about underlying knowledge, that your answer is pretty useless.  It is true that we can consider the universe a quantum field and that that particles are a state in that field, but that is so far from giving understanding that you might was well not have started.  If you are going down that path, the explanation will need to include what the heck is a quantum field, what the heck do you mean by a "state" in that field, etc.  That's a 1 semester course.

Comment: @sid138: It doesn't take a whole semester to learn that: 1) there is only one quantum field 2) that quantum field is global 3) particles are merely (quasi-)conserved states of that field (in the same sense as "spin up" is a state or "1s" is a state. With these three simple rules you can avoid ALL conceptual problems of wave-particle duality and you have not encumbered the student with any historical ballast that not even the folks who came up with it had much trust in. I am honestly having a hard time understanding the motivation behind teaching falsehoods for the sake of "simplification".

Comment: @CuriousOne, you are correct that the rules are simple, but the ramification are way complex.  So, while you have these nice, simple rules, those rules say nothing about what those states mean from an observational point of view.  These rules do not state that when you look for wave characteristics that is what you will find and if you look for particle characteristics that is also what you will find.  In fact, these rules say nothing about the interactions between the observed and the observer.  So, the "simplifying" explanations are a start down the path of observer/observed interactions.

Comment: @sid138: Observations are simply numbers that describe phenomena. That's no different in classical mechanics, either. If you want "meaning", then you have to go to philosophy and other arts. In science the only "meaning" is that we can describe the observations we make with as high a precision as possible. You are simply looking for things that don't exist. Quantum fields are quantum fields. They are not waves and they are not particles and they are certainly not both. You have been told the wrong thing for too long and now you can't let go but that's no reason to perpetuate false teachings.

Answer (score 2):

There is simply no such thing as an electron that "goes from place to place". That electrons are little hard balls is simply an implicit assumption that we carry over from the macroscopic into the microscopic world. It's also a false assumption.

The best way to think of an electron is in form of quantization and conservation laws that are valid for a quantum field. An electron is a lepton and leptons have a lepton quantum number that is conserved. So once you have an "electron", i.e. a lepton number of (let's call it $L$) of 1, you can't get rid of it. When we measure an electron, all it means is that we have found a quantum field to have a $L=1$ at some location. How that number got from one point of that quantum field to another point is described by the laws of quantum mechanics and it does prescribe interference trough multiple paths, but at no time did a solid little ball do all the motions of the quantum field that are necessary to get from $L=1$ at one point to $L=1$ at another point.

Comment: I don't think that the OP has the background to understand this answer.

Comment: @gonenc: this is about as simple as one can make it. A electron is an accounting number and not a hard ball. It's for sure better for the OP to hear it now than to be sent on a wild goose chase trough an 80 year old error of judgement called "wave-particle duality" that she will have to abandon anyway because it's patently false and always was. See the post by sid138 for a near perfect example of how one should not treat the question in the year 2015.